# Connecting an iPad to a printer on another (LAN) network

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, pdf, printing

I am wondering if it is possible to issue a command to print a PDF file from my iPad (connected to a WiFi network), to a printer which is connected to a LAN, provided I know the (global) IP address or URL of the printer.

I routinely print research papers, and to do this, I have to issue a command from a Mac or a laptop to print the PDF file. But I'd like to be able to do this from my iPad.

Is this possible? I haven't found any app on the App Store which can do this, but I haven't tried all possible apps of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many years, I have been using Readdle's Printer Pro application for iOS. The app costs a few dollars, but seems to do the trick for me. It also works with all other Readdle apps, such as Scanner Pro, and Documents 5.

Printer Pro - print documents, photos, web pages and email attachments by Readdle
https://appsto.re/ca/hVxCx.i

Comment: Thanks @bret7600. But according to the app description, it seems to be an interface between your iPad and a Mac connected to the printer. Does this app work if I just have an iPad and the printer is a network printer, not connected to a computer?

Comment: The app works without a mac interface. It only needs the IP of the printer. Can put up screenshots if needed.

Comment: http://imgur.com/6cHNWgg